# iOS tableView not displaying sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a table view that is embedded inside a regular view controller (which is embedded inside a navigation controller.)

Generally speaking, calling methods such as `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` work fine, they are seen and function properly....

Now comes the problem of displaying sections.  For some strange reason the method `numberOfSectionsInTableview:` is *not* being seen when the program runs.  I've tested this by inserting `NSLog`'s as well as inserting breakpoints.  Nothing is being recognized inside this method.  When calling to display sections (I'm organizing it all through `NSFetchedResultsController`) it only displays the first section when it currently should display 5 (because `numberOfSectionsInTableview` is not required and defaults to 1.)

I'm thinking this is happening because of my tableView being embedded inside a view controller rather than it actually being a tableview controller.  But if that's the case, why do I not need to do anything special for the other `tableView:` methods?  As best I can tell, the sectionInfo part of the code (inside the NSFetchedResultsController) is set up properly since the other `section` methods are working properly (put `NSLog` inside each one to ensure the method is called.)

Any help you can give at understanding and/or correcting this issue would be greatly appreciated!  Let me know if you need any more info on my code.

**EDIT**

Here is all the code I'm using as it relates to this field:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ActiveList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];

    //[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[ sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2 ]];

    // Only retrieves items where 'isActive' SQLite field is '1' or 'YES'
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isActive == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                              initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                              managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                              sectionNameKeyPath:@"category"
                              cacheName:@"ActiveLists"];


    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
}
return fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)performFetch {

NSError *error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
    return;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


[self performFetch];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, `tableView` is the parameter.. `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableView { retrun [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];` That's the full method I use

Comment: are you sure this method is invoked yet? Did you check by putting breakpoint?

Comment: @Anil yes, I did insert breakpoints as well as inserted `NSLog`.  It is *not* being invoked, which is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Table view inside a view controller rather than a tableViewController is not an issue. It should work in both cases

Comment: That's what I figured too but I can't figure out why it isn't firing

Comment: @JTSmith can you put your code here? That's help.

Comment: @JTSmith Also have you implemented - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

Comment: @Rushi Yes... This is the problem, I've put that in but it's not firing.  I've added the code to my question

Comment: fetchedResultsController.dataSource = self; is not set

Comment: @PeterCen all my other fetchedResultsController method calls function properly.  Could your solution still be the case?

Comment: You should be setting it nonetheless, try it

Comment: @Rushi see my comment on his answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. Are you sure your other methods are being called? Where is your UITableView?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24608/discussion-between-peter-cen-and-jt-smith)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be a capitalization in numberOfSectionsInTableView where the v was not capitalized.

Comment: Peter, you are AWESOME man! If I could give you more points for all the effort of going to chat and looking through my source files all to find a simple lowercase letter, then I would... Thanks for all your help my man!

Comment: No problem, always use autocomplete :)

Comment: I wish I could undelete my first comment :-P